# How does the default value in django's low level cache work?

Tags: python, django, caching

I'm noticing a difference in behaviour between these 2 code block, although from my understanding of the django docs, they should be the same.

utils.py

```
from django.core.cache import cache
import logging

def get_cm_subscribers_from_api():
    logger.info('Missed the cache.')
    cm_subscribers = [u'someone@example.com', u'someonelse@example.com']
    cache.set('cm_subscribers', cm_subscribers, 30)
    return cm_subscribers


def get_cm_subscribers_version1():
    cm_subscribers = cache.get('cm_subscribers')
    if not cm_subscribers:
        cm_subscribers = get_cm_subscribers_from_api()
    return cm_subscribers


def get_cm_subscribers_version2():
    cm_subscribers = cache.get('cm_subscribers', get_cm_subscribers_from_api())
    return cm_subscribers
```

In the interactive interpreter I do this:

```
>>> from utils import get_cm_subscribers_version1, get_cm_subscribers_version2
>>> get_cm_subscribers_version1()
INFO: Missed the cache.
[u'someone@example.com', u'someonelse@example.com']
>>> get_cm_subscribers_version1()
[u'someone@example.com', u'someonelse@example.com']
#The second function keeps on missing the cache:
>>> get_cm_subscribers_version2()
INFO: Missed the cache.
[u'someone@example.com', u'someonelse@example.com']
>>> get_cm_subscribers_version2()
INFO: Missed the cache.
[u'someone@example.com', u'someonelse@example.com']
```

Doesn't `cache.get` execute the second argument only when the key doesn't exist in the cache? It seems to get executed no matter what.

I'm using no special settings, so the default cache backend applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: this is perfectly normal function calling semantics.

In order for Python to call a function - in this case `cache.get()` - it needs to know the value of all of its arguments. If one of the arguments is itself a function call, then that call must be made to resolve the value, before the outer function can be called.

(Note that it is possible to write a function that accepts a callable - for example, `get_cm_subscribers_from_api` without the calling brackets - and for the function to determine that the parameter is callable, and call it only when necessary. But that's up to the writer of the function, and isn't anything you can affect in the calling code.)

Comment: Clear and precise answer. Thanks.